# HAProxy SRV record load-balancing using Consul DNS prepared queries

Tags: dns, load-balancing, haproxy, consul, service-discovery

I am attempting to perform **load-balancing with HAProxy with services registered in Consul, using Consul's DNS SRV records**.

My Consul DNS is properly configured to resolve the following:

```
$ dig my-service.service.consul SRV

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
my-service.service.consul. 0 IN SRV 1 1 8000 node1.node.dc.consul.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
node1.node.dc.consul. 10 IN A   X.X.X.X
node1.node.dc.consul. 10 IN TXT "consul-network-segment="
```

And also with a Consul *prepared query*:

```
$ dig geo-my-service.query.consul SRV

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
geo-my-service.query.consul. 10 IN SRV 1 1 8000 node1.node.dc.consul.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
node1.node.dc.consul. 10 IN A   X.X.X.X
node1.node.dc.consul. 10 IN TXT "consul-network-segment="
```

I successfully configured the barebone service query in HAProxy with the following block:

```
backend my-service

    balance roundrobin
    server-template my-service-api 1 _my-service._tcp.service.consul check resolvers consul
```

However, when I use the Consul prepared query, I get a **Socket error: No port available for the TCP connection** error on the given service in HAProxy:

```
backend companion_authnz

    balance roundrobin
    server-template my-service-api 1 _geo-my-service._tcp.query.consul check resolvers consul
```

I cannot find any information in neither HAProxy nor Consul documentation about resolving prepared queries in HAProxy.

**Has anyone ever had experience with Consul prepared queries and plugging them in HAProxy using SRV records?**

I am using Consul 1.1.0 and HAProxy 1.8.9. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I successfully plugged a prepared query in HAProxy by using A records and specifying the service port in the config file:

```
backend my-service

    balance roundrobin
    server-template my-service-api 1 geo-my-service.query.consul:8000 check resolvers consul
```

However, **that would be nice to use SRV records in order for the port to be dynamically resolved** by HAProxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

First of all, the *service* (_my-service._tcp.service.consul) resolution is expected, as stated in [this](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html#rfc-2782-lookup) section of Consul's DNS interface documentation.
Consul's DNS is configured to resolve services with this form (RFC 2782):

```
_service._protocol[.service][.datacenter][.consul]
```

This is why `_my-service._tcp.service.consul` was working properly.

However, my prepared query was also configured to match this regex: **^geo-(.*?)$**, so when I was running `dig _geo-my-service._tcp.query.consul`, it **wasn't matchin the regex**, thus no resolution. That explains why I couldn't resolve the prepared query while respecting the RFC 2782 standard address.

That being said, HAProxy **requires an RFC 2782 compliant address** to resolve a SRV record.
To deal with these constraints, I had to do two changes to my setup:

1. I changed my prepared query regex to **^_geo-(.*?)$** so the RFC 2782 address would match
2. I omitted the protocol (._tcp.) in the HAProxy configuration file so that Consul would find the query

Here are the results:

```
$ dig _geo-my-service.query.consul SRV

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_geo-my-service.query.consul. 10 IN SRV 1 1 8000 node1.node.dc.consul.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
node1.node.dc.consul. 10 IN A   X.X.X.X
node1.node.dc.consul. 10 IN TXT "consul-network-segment="
```

And for the HAProxy configuration:

```
backend my-service

    balance roundrobin
    server-template my-service-api 1 _geo-my-service.query.consul check resolvers consul
```

In conclusion, I think that this behavior is a bit odd and that RFC 2782 standard should work the same for both Consul services and prepared queries.

Comment: "HAProxy requires an RFC 2782 compliant address to resolve a SRV record" helped me a lot!

Comment: Make sure to increase `accepted_payload_size` in the resolvers section, otherwise when the response of the DNS query exceeds the default value of 512, service discovery won't work. I'd recommended setting it to the maximum value; `accepted_payload_size 8192`. Ref: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#5.3.2-accepted_payload_size